# Determining if a Graph is a Tree

Tags: graph, tree

Most solution to this problem propose to do a Depth/Breadth first search.

I however use the following constraints to determine whether a graph is a tree:

1. All nodes have one parent only, except root which has no parent;
2. All nodes are connected: they have 1 parent or N children;

It seems this is not sufficient. Why? Can you provide an example respecting my constraints which is not a tree?

Comment: What is the difference between parent and children? The graph is not directed.

Comment: How do you know it is not sufficient? Presumably a parent is a node that you have marked as being closer to the root. A general graph data structure doesn't normally make a distinction between parent and child.

Comment: @LeeNeverGup: I believe you answered my problem;). I assumed (u, v) with u parent and v child, which is actually not the case. Thanks!

Comment: @B...: indeed, this was my mistake. I assumed that given edges (u,v) was for u parent and v child which is not true. I see my mistake now! Thanks;)

Comment: @LeeNeverGup: make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Korchkidu As you wish

Comment: Simple characterization is: Graph is a tree iff it is connected and has |V|-1 edges. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general undirected graph, you cannot determine who is the child and who is the parent.